# Oracle double select issue

Tags: oracle, select, rownum

So I have these 2 tables on Oracle:

CLIENT

```
cl_id  cl_name
1      John
2      Maria
```

PAYMENTS

```
pa_id  pa_date        pa_status   cl_id
1      2017-01-01     1           1
2      2017-01-01     1           2
3      2017-02-01     1           1
4      2017-02-01     1           2
5      2017-03-01     0           1
6      2017-03-01     1           2
```

I need a select statemant that gives me the client ID, NAME and the STATUS of his **last** payment. So the end result of my select should be:

```
cl_id  cl_name  pa_status
1      John     0
2      Maria    1
```

This is the CLIENT select that works:

`select cl_id, cl_name from CLIENT;`

This is the last status of the PAYMENT select that works:

`select * from (
select pa_status from PAYMENT ORDER BY PA_DATE DESC) 
where rownum = 1;`

So now, I need to make them work together. I tried 2 ways that didn't work:

`select cl_id, cl_name, (select * from (
select pa_status from PAYMENT ORDER BY PA_DATE DESC) 
where rownum = 1 and PAYMENT.cl_id = CLIENT.CL_ID) as last_status from CLIENT;`

error:  invalid identifier

AND this:

`select cl_id, cl_name, (select * from (
select pa_status from PAYMENT ORDER BY PA_DATE DESC) 
where rownum = 1 ) as last_status from CLIENT;`

which don't give me any errors, but only shows the same last status of John that is the last record:

```
cl_id cl_name  last_status
1     John     0
2     Maria    0
```

Can anyone give me a hint?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use analystic function.
This kind of functions let you split your data to some groups, and rank the data for each group as you wish.

In your case:

```
Select * from (
Select id, name, status, row_number () over (partition by      p.cl_id order by p.pa_date desc) as rw
From client c join payments p on p.cl_id = c.cl_id)
Inn where inn.rw = 1;
```

Comment: great. There is even better syntax for that - look for FIRST analystic function. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This gets the max date for the client
and then gets the highest payment id with that date.

```
with max_date as (
      select max(date) as max_date, cl_id from payments group by cl_id
)
select c.cl_id, c.cl_name, p.pa_sttus from client c
join payments p
on c.cl_id = p.cl_id
where p.pa_id = (select max(p2.pa_id) from payments p2
                  join max_date md
                  on p2.cl_id = md.cl_id
                  where p.cl_id = p2.cl_id 
                  and p2.pa_date = md.max_date
                  )
```

Comment: This gives me an invalid identifier on the last line: "md.pa_date"

Answer (score 0):

First take the max of date from for each clientid.

```
Select cl_id, max(pa_date) as pa_date from PAYMENTS group by cl_id
```

Now you take ur client table and join with above subquery

```
select c.cl_id, c.cl_name,
(select pa_status from PAYMENT t where t.pa_date=p.pa_date and t.cl_id=p.cl_id)
from CLIENT c join (Select cl_id, max(pa_date) as pa_date from PAYMENTS group by cl_id) p on p.cl_id=c.cl_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Oracle's `KEEP LAST` here:

```
select cl_id, c.cl_name, last_payment.status
from client
join
(
  select 
    cl_id,
    max(pa_status) keep (dense_rank last order by pa_date) as status
  from payments
  group by cl_id
) last_payment using (cl_id);
```

(If you want to include clients without payments, change the join to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.)